# Stop JUnit from finishing until all other threads have been stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, javafx

During my Unit tests, I'd like to plot some figures using Java FX. Now the problem is that as soon as the Unit test are done, the JVM and thus Java FX shut down and I am not able to inspect the generated plots (unlike in the case where the "test" is just started from the main method). So my question is, is there a way to stop JUnit from exiting before particular threads are finished, i.e. to replicate the behaviour as the test is started from the main method directly? And yes, I am aware that plotting is most likely not really something which should be done during a unit test in general.
At the moment I am doing something like this:

```
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DummyConfig.class }) 
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MainViewTest {

    private boolean fromMain = false;

    // starting the "test" from main does not require explicit waiting for 
    // for the JavaFX thread to finish .. I'd like to replicate this
    // behaviour in JUnit (by configuring JUnit, not my test or application code)
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new MainViewTest(true).test();
    }

    public MainViewTest(){}

    private MainViewTest(boolean fromMain){
        this.fromMain = fromMain;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        //do some tests....

        //plot some results...
        PlotStage.plotStage(new QPMApplication() {
            @Override
            public Stage createStage() {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                StackPane root = new StackPane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
                stage.setTitle("Stage");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                        Platform.exit();
                    }
                 });
                return stage;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Stage started");
        // how to get rid of this block (or using a countdownlatch) but
        // still waiting for the threads to finish?
        Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        if (!fromMain) {
            System.out.println("checking threads...");
            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                if (thread.getName().contains("JavaFX")) {
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is here that I want to get rid of this nasty block to wait until all the JavaFX platform is explicitly exited. 
I appreciate the answer regarding using a countdown latch instead of joining the Java FX thread explicitly. However this still requires me to explictly stop the current thread. However, I would rather like to "tell" JUnit somehow to wait for the JavaFX thread to finish.

So basically what I am looking for is a way to tell JUnit to wait for particular threads without any blocking code inside my test methods.

Appendix: Necessary classes for a minimal running example

```
public class PlotStage {

    public static boolean toolkitInialized = false;

    public static void plotStage(QPMApplication stageCreator) {
        if (!toolkitInialized) {
            Thread appThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Application.launch(InitApp.class);
                }
            });
            appThread.start();
        }

        while (!toolkitInialized) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Stage stage = stageCreator.createStage();
                stage.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class InitApp extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
            toolkitInialized = true;
        }
    }
}


public interface QPMApplication {
   public abstract  Stage createStage();
}
```

Comment: The CountDownLatch approach mentioned below is good, but your test doesn't appear to be performing any verification/assertion which means the only two outcomes are succeed or throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for that.

1. Initialize with `1`.
2. When the `Stage` is closed, invoke `countDown()`.
3. In the JUnit Test, call `await()` to wait for the `Stage` to be closed.

Example:

```
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
// TODO show the stage and do not forget to add cdl.countDown() to your
//   stage.setOnCloseRequest
cdl.await();
```

---

Alternative #1:

Use the [JavaFX Junit Rule](https://gist.github.com/andytill/3835914) to perform all actions directly on the FX application Thread.

---

Alternative #2:

Use [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX), for what I read from your updated description, it fits best.

Comment: This requires adding test elements (a cdl) to your main code?

Comment: @RaGe Yes, it does. Because JavaFX's primary `Stage` can not be shown in a blocking way. Blocking has to be done the other way round, which can easily be done using the `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Adding code to your main codebase that serves no function except to enable a specific test case sounds like bad practice to me. I prefer OP's thread.join() way.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I edited the question in order to make my intend more clear. Basically I want to get rid of all explicit threading code which would not be necessary if the same code would be run from main directly (i.e. if the "test" is run from main, I don't have to wait explicity)